# Set "use strict" for plugins

Tags: javascript, module

I'm writing a JavaScript-Software that is able to load and work with plugins.

These plugins can also be written by other users.

Now I want to modify my plugin-manager, that it sets the `"use strict"`-option for all the modules - is this possible?

**This is how the plugins are currently written:**

```
"use strict";  //I want to add this command automatically by the plugin-manager
window.pluginName = {
    "version": "0.1",
    "attribute": function(){},
    ...
}
```

**How Plugins are being loaded:**

I make an ajax-Request to the js-File (which contains exacly one plugin). When the file is ready, I access it via "`var newPlugin = window[pluginName];`"

Is is possible to automatically use strict-mode, or do I have to rely that the plugin-writer uses this flag for debugging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strict mode is defined in variable scope, so the only way to set "use strict" for each plugin is to put the declarative in the functions at the top, or in some function that encompasses all the plugin definitions.

The only other way to affect all plugins would be to define it globally, and that wouldn't be a good idea unless you're absolutely certain that all JavaScript that will run will work properly in strict mode.

Comment: My plugins currently define it "globaly" - at the beginning of the file. Does it also affect other included js-files, or is it limited to the own file? Furthermore, if I define it in the middle of a file - will it also affect previous code?

Comment: If they are separate scripts, then `"use strict"` should only affect that one script, even if it's global. Not sure what you mean by "in the middle of a file" though. The declarative needs to be at the top of a function or at the top of the file. It should be the first statement executed in that function or file. The function may be in the middle of a file, and `"use strict"` will only affect that function's scope.